# (Elementary Number Theory) Using Wilson's Theorem ..??

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the difficulty in solving the question in elementary number theory.
The problem is :

If n is a composite integer, n divides (n-1)! except when n=4.

This chapter in which I have a question contain Wilson's theorem and Fermat's little theorem. So, I think that this problem can be solved by using these two theorem.(Or either)
But, I don't know how to solve this.
If you answer this question, then I appreciate you ! ^^

Comment: You need neither Fermat's Theorem nor Wilson's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. If $n=ab$ with $a\neq b$, and $1<a,b<n$, then how do you ascertain that $ab\mid (n-1)!$?
2. If $n=p^2$, with $p>2$ a prime, then show that $p(2p)\mid (n-1)!$.
3. Show that the above two bullets cover all the composite numbers except $n=4$.